# How can make simple bind the default for ldapsearch?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have the following in my `~/.ldaprc`:

```
uri ldaps://my.corporate.ldap.server.com
base DC=corp,DC=companyname,DC=com
bindn CN=Ruben,OU=Users,OU=companyname,OU=SE,OU=Resources,DC=corp,DC=companyname,DC=com
```

currently I can search by

```
ldapsearch -x -W '(displayName=Ruben*)` sAMAccountName
```

Is there any way to avoid having to pass the `-x` every time?  If I don't include it tries to use SASL, and `man ldap.conf` does not help very much. Is there any value of `SASL_MECH` or `SASL_*` that can be used to trigger the "Use simple authentication instead of SASL" behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If using bash for your shell, you could define an alias:

`alias ldapsearch='ldapsearch -x'`

(Other shells also support aliases but defining them is different for each)

Now anytime you run `ldapsearch` it will be replaced with `ldapsearch -x`, so now all you have to type is `ldapsearch -W '(displayName=Ruben*)' sAMAccountName`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to force the simple bind but it's possible to get more or less the **same behaviour as simple bind with SASL DIGEST-MD5** like so:

```
# ~/.ldaprc
uri ldaps://my.corporate.ldap.server.com
base DC=corp,DC=companyname,DC=com
sasl_mech DIGEST-MD5
SASL_NOCANON on
SASL_AUTHCID rubelagu
SASL_REALM
VERSION 3
```

Where the `SASL_AUTHCID` is usually your username (your `sAMAccountName` if you are using Active Directory). In my case `SASL_REALM` is the empty string and I use `SASL_NOCANON` to prevent ldapsearch from sending `digest-uri` as `ldap/1.1.1.1` as Active Directory will complain in that case with `The digest-uri does not match any LDAP SPN's registered for this server.` , With `SASL_NOCANON on` the digest-uri will be `ldap/my.corporate.ldap.server.com` which is what Active Directory expects

Comment: I've never heard of Active Directory _supporting_ DIGEST-MD5, much less expecting it. But I have to ask, why not just let ldapsearch use SASL GSSAPI if it's AD?

Comment: I never said that AD expects DIGEST-MD5, I said that it expects SASL_NOCANON (or rather it expect the digest-uri to be non-canonicalized), but certainly DIGEST-MD5 works. I tried with `-Y GSSAPI` (from Linux) and it get `SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error:  The context has expire (Success)`. So for my case, ldapsearch from a linux machine to the corporate AD I only managed to get simple bind and SASL DIGEST-MD5 to work.